# I am trying to reset to factory, but the menu says I need to update, but there isnt enough room on the device to update

Tags: iphone, software-update, restore

I followed the recovery directions to trigger the recovery menu for the locked iphone 7.

[image]

When I go to restore the phone to factory settings, I get a menu that says I need to update the phone.

How can I restore this phone to factory settings?

[image]

When I click install, I am notified that I do not have enough space and the restore stops.

[image]

If I try to skip the update by pushing "not now" the restore does not continue. The same issue happens when I try to just update the phone separately first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Installation failed" message is letting you know that you haven't got sufficient free disk space available on your *computer*. Not the device.

So you just need to free some disk space on your computer, then you can download the necessary update and restore the iPhone to factory settings.